# What is the correct way to declare a structure, or just a variable, in Rust that can be passed to C code expecting a pointer?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around declaring mutable (or pointer) variables and interacting with C code through FFI. I've been playing with this for most of the day and have found conflicting examples due to how quickly Rust is developing. :)

The situation is like this: I have a C function which takes in a pointer to a `struct`, this struct has fields that are `int`s and `char *`s.  My understanding is that I need to declare a similar struct in Rust to pass to the `extern C` function.

---

Here are my example files I've written while trying to figure this out:

```
main.rs
extern crate libc;

struct testStruct {
  an_int: libc::c_int,
  a_string: *mut libc::c_char
}

extern {
  fn start_test(test: *mut testStruct) -> libc::c_int;
}

fn main() {
  // println!("Hello, world!");
  let test_struct = testStruct { an_int: 1, a_string: "hello" };
  start_test(&mut test_struct);
}
```

--

```
test_file.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_file.h"

struct test_struct {
    int an_int;
    char *a_string;
};

int start_client(struct test_struct *test) {
    printf("Test function!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously the actual code is more complex, I'm just trying to get a basic example working to understand how mutability/pointers work in Rust with FFI.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I'm also not clear on what the question is, but I have one additional comment: the testStruct should be #[repr(C)]`.

Comment: Added a line to clarify what my actual question is, but any prod in the right direction regarding pointers and FFI in Rust is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the correct way to declare a structure, or just a variable, in Rust that can be passed to C code expecting a pointer?

The memory layout of a struct is undefined (the compiler is allowed to reorder fields, for instance) unless you add the `#[repr(C)]` attribute to the struct. This attribute gives the struct a layout compatible with C.

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct TestStruct {
    an_int: libc::c_int,
    a_string: *mut libc::c_char
}
```

Using a raw pointer in the struct works fine, but we can do better. There are two other important types in Rust that are only composed of a pointer: borrowed pointers (`&'a T` or `&'a mut T`) and `Box<T>`. You can use these types instead `*const T` or `*mut T` to make it clear that the pointer borrows an existing value (and enables the compiler to validate that the pointer doesn't outlive its referent) or points to an object on the heap that should be dropped when the pointer (or the struct containing it) goes out of scope. However, be careful with `Box<T>`, since you could accidentally free a value while the C code still has a pointer to the value.

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct TestStruct<'a> {
    an_int: libc::c_int,
    a_string: &'a mut libc::c_char
}
```

Another thing to watch out for is the use of fat pointers. In Rust, some pointer types are *fat*, i.e. they carry additional data along with the pointer. For example, slices (`*const [T]`, `*mut [T]`, `&'a [T]`, `&'a mut [T]`) can be thought of as a struct or tuple containing a pointer to the first item and the number of items in the slice (a `usize`); trait objects (`*const T`, `*mut T`, `&'a T`, `&'a mut T` where `T` is the name of a trait) are composed of a pointer to the object and a pointer to the virtual method table for the trait implementation. You should avoid using these types when defining a Rust struct matching a C struct.

You can find more information on using Rust's FFI in [the FFI section of the Rust book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ffi.html).

Comment: I found the `Box<T>` comment interesting. What do you mean by accidental freeing when compared to local variable? Isn't it also possible in the same way if you use the `TestStruct<'a>` from your second example, and do `fn foo() { let mut ts = TestStruct {...}; start_test(&mut ts); }` ? If  `a_string` is generated in `foo` (for example ref'd local string) and `start_test` saves the pointer for later, rust will also free it, right?

Comment: You're right, the same issue could occur with a local variable and a borrowed pointer in the struct. This will catch lifetime errors in the Rust code, but not in the C code. There's a reason why calling `extern` functions is unsafe, after all. :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought there's some specific issue on top of that in case of Boxes :)

Comment: @FrancisGagné Thank you for the detailed explanation in your answer, I'll play around with this today and mark it as accepted!